# game tag needs to be cleaned up

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[game](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/game) needs to be merged into [games](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/games). I've taken care of merging in ubuntu-games already.

Answer (score 1):

Done. Thank your for your attention to detail!